# Prove it's topology

Tags: general-topology

First let's understand who these topologies are:
\begin{equation}
    \tau_1 = \{\{m \in \mathbb{N} : m < n\} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\mathbb{N}\}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \tau_1=\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\}, \{0,1,2,3\}, \cdots, \mathbb{N}\}
\end{equation}

Let's verify that $\tau_1$ is a topology:

1. In fact, $\emptyset$ is subnext to any set, so $\emptyset \in \tau_1$, plus $\mathbb{N}\in \tau_1$.
2. We need to show that the finite intersection of the $\tau_1$ elements belongs to $\tau_1$. I can see that yes, for example, $\{0\}\cap \{0,1\}=\{0\}\in \tau_1$, $\{0\}\cap\{0,1\}\cap\{0,1,2\}=\{0\}\in \tau_1$ or $\{0,1\}\cap\{0,1,2\}\in \tau_1$. But I can't generalize. Can you help me?
3. We need to show that the arbitrary union of $\tau_1$ elements belongs to $\tau_1$. I know it's worth that, for example, $\{0\}\cup \{0,1\}\cup \{0,1,2\} \cup \mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N} \in \tau_1$. But I can't generalize. Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: It helps to note that $$\varnothing\subset \{0\}\subset \{0,1\}\subset \{0,1,2\}\subset \cdots.$$

Comment: Yeah, That I know. My difficulty is to generalize.

Comment: Note that any intersection is equal to the smallest of the sets, which is in the collection of sets. A union will be the biggest set, which is in the collection of sets. You’ve already said this, but you just need to state it generally, and then you’ve shown what you wanted to.

Comment: @milou See Benjamin's comment, it follows as a consequence of my comment. This shows properties 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Given finitely many sets of the form $\{0, \ldots, k_1\}, \ldots, \{0, \ldots, k_n\}$, can you see what the intersection must be? What if you put $k = \min\{k_1, \ldots, k_n\}$. What could it be?
   Of course, intersecting further with $\varnothing$ or $\Bbb N$ is easy.
2. Let $I$ be an arbitrary set and for each $i \in I$, suppose you are given $\{0, \ldots, k_i\}$. If the set $\{k_i\}$ is bounded, can you see deduce the union? (What if you consider $\max_{i \in I} k_i$?) What if the set is not bounded? Do you think the union is then $\Bbb N$?
   As before, taking a further union with $\varnothing$ or $\Bbb N$ is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Set $U_n=\{m\in\mathbb{N}:m<n\}$ and $U_\infty=\mathbb{N}$. Then $U_0=\emptyset$, so $\emptyset\in\tau_1$.

Consider a finite (nonempty) set of members of $\tau_1$ and write it as
$$
\{U_{n_1},U_{n_2},\dots,U_{n_k}\}
$$
Prove that $\bigcap_{i=1}^k U_{n_i}=U_n$, where $n=\min\{n_1,\dots,n_k\}$.

Suppose you have an arbitrary set of members of $\tau_1$. The set is $\{U_{n_i}:i\in I\}$. Now consider $\sup\{n_i:i\in I\}$.

Comment: How can we justify $\{U_{n_i}:i\in I\}$ with the supreme will belong to $\tau_1$?

Comment: @milou Simple: prove that $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_{n_i}=U_{s}$, where $s=\sup\{n_i:i\in I\}$.